# Which advatanges has @Schedule over an own implementation?

Tags: spring, scheduling

We're using Spring, and I suggested to my colleague that he should use `@Schedule` instead of coding the behaviour manually with a `Runnable` and `Thread.sleep()`.

I pointed out that the annotation is more "high level", more descriptive and better configurable and testable, but this wasn't convincing enough. He argued that he needs just a very simple behaviour, so using "magic" would be over the top and cause unnecessary overhead.

Did I miss some good arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is generally related to *the level of abstraction* that you want to achieve. Before getting to some answers, I believe it's worth to ask:

> How much *static* is the piece of code? In other words, how often the piece you refer to will change through time, either in the *logic* or in the *schedule* that it needs to run on?

Based on this question, I think that no matter what framework/library is going to be used, one thing should be respected:

> The logic of the task should *not* be interleaved with *scheduling* aspect of it.

So, either using Spring or any other scheduling library has the first side effect that *a separate abstraction* is provided for the piece of task apart from the piece that schedules and runs it.

Therefore, as long as the separation of concern and required abstraction is present, I think it would be OK not to use any specific library. On the other hand, if, for instance, Spring DI is not used to run the task, then it could again be argued that it's not really necessary to use Spring.

Based on my understanding of the problem, I would suggest to use Java's Timer abstraction at least if Spring seems too much for the problem.